# Sync two scrolls with different sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have been trying to sync two different divs with different sizes. As you can see in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0dix/oewsua58/74/) I'm almost there. But while move the bigger horizontal scroll the inner one doesn't finish at its final scroll end. I want both to be synchronized, start and finish in their own sizes. I have tried to play with their width but cannot make it work. I believe an offset is missing.

```
 $(function() {
   // move along with container
   $('#container').on('scroll', e => {
     $('#container2').css(
       'transform',
       `translate(${e.target.scrollLeft}px, ${e.target.scrollTop}px)`,
     );

     const containerElement = $('#container'),
       bigPanelElement = $('#big-panel'),
       container2Element = $('#container2'),
       bigPanelWidth = bigPanelElement.width(),
       bigPanelHeight = bigPanelElement.height(),
       containerScrollLeft = containerElement.scrollLeft(),
       container2ScrollLeft = container2Element.scrollLeft(),
       containerScrollTop = containerElement.scrollTop(),
       container2Width = container2Element.width(),
       container2Height = container2Element.height();

     const newScrollLeft =
       bigPanelWidth === 0 ?
       0 :
       (container2Width * containerScrollLeft) /
        bigPanelWidth,
       newScrollTop =
       bigPanelHeight === 0 ?
       0 :
       (container2Height * containerScrollTop) /
       bigPanelHeight;

     //console.log(`newScrollLeft ${newScrollLeft}`);

     container2Element.scrollLeft(newScrollLeft).scrollTop(newScrollTop);

   });
 });
```

Secondly, would be nice to have that the inner horizontal scroll also scroll the outer one in sync too.

Comment: You need to consider the [<] and [>] parts of the scrollbar.  Seems to be about 15px (probably 14) so would be that x2 `(container2Width - 30) * containerScrollLeft)`.  https://jsfiddle.net/rqb36gL4/ Haven't been able to find a way to get this programmatically, so it would not work across all browsers unless you styled the scrollbars yourself.  There's probably a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made it work [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0dix/oewsua58/122/).

Instead of use the div widths I use the scroll bar width.

```
const maxScrollLeft = containerElement[0].scrollWidth - containerElement[0].clientWidth;
const maxScrollTop = containerElement[0].scrollHeight - containerElement[0].clientHeight;

const maxScrollLeft2 = container2Element[0].scrollWidth - container2Element[0].clientWidth;
const maxScrollTop2 = container2Element[0].scrollHeight - container2Element[0].clientHeight;

const percLeft = containerScrollLeft / maxScrollLeft;
const percTop = containerScrollTop / maxScrollTop;

const newScrollLeft = Math.ceil(percLeft * maxScrollLeft2);
const newScrollTop = Math.ceil(percTop * maxScrollTop2);
```

Thanks anyway.